# How to make website dropdownlist work better for iPhone

Tags: c#, asp.net, iphone

I'm developing a website for intra company use; most of the users will have iPhones.  There are several dropdownlists which can have hundreds of choices (for example, a vendor list); with a keyboard this isn't a problem because you can just type the first characters of the required value and zoom in.  With the iPhone you get that very clever rotating finder; but the keyboard doesn't appear and it takes many finger flicks to get to the end of the alphabet.

Does anyone have suggestions which will make the user experience a little easier for iPhone users but work well with other machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try an **ajax enabled auto complete text box instead of a drop down**.  Check out

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

This way the user can still type to search for an entry but the safari UI won't force them to select one since its just a text box.